# BackboneJS + Codeigniter RESTful API - How to fetch API containing variables

Tags: api, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have this Backbone App where I want to fetch data, depending on the ID I get from an Artist. In this case I want the biography to be fetched. The Restful API is build with Codeigniter. Right now I'm not getting any errors, just no data so, does anyone know how to fetch an API which contains variables in Backbone?

```
public function artist_bio_get()  
{ 
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT artist_bio.bio FROM artist_bio INNER JOIN artists ON artists.artist_id = artist_bio.artist_id WHERE artist_bio.artist_id = '$artist_id'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

    if($data) {
        $this->response($data, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    } else {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artist biography!'), 404);
    }
}
```

My Backbone View looks like this:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var Artistbio = App.module();

    Artistbio.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'artistbio',
        template: 'artistbio',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render)
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });
    Artistbio.ArtistbioCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/projects/mdk/index.php/api/artistchannel/artist_bio';
        }
    });;

    return Artistbio;
}
```

**[[UPDATE]]**:

ok I changed my View like this:

```
Artistbio.ArtistbioCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/projects/mdk/index.php/api/artistchannel/artist_bio/' + this.artist_id;
        }
});
```

Then, in my MainView I did:

```
var artistbioCollection = new Artistbio.ArtistbioCollection();
artistbioCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
this.insertView(new Artistbio.View({collection: artistbioCollection}));
artistbioCollection.fetch();
```

And then, I made an controller like this:

```
ArtistController.prototype.initArtist = function(letter, id) {
     App.trigger('navigate', 'artistchannel');
     this.artistView.artist_id = id;
     App.useLayout('artistchannel', 'artistchannel').setViews({
        '.artistsDiv': this.artistView
     }).render();
};
```

When I enter an ID in my MySQL query, like `WHERE artist_bio.artist_id = '86'";` - I get the right result, but when I keep the `$artist_id`, it gives me the error **`Undefined variable: artist_id`**

What could be the issue here?

**[[UPDATE 2]]**

I have made a controller like this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
  var ArtistModule = require('modules/artist');
  var ArtistController = function(navigation) {
     this.navigation = navigation;
     this.artistView =  new ArtistModule.View();
 };
```

And then my artistview-module

```
define([

'app',
'backbone',
'modules/artistBio',
'modules/artistRelated',
'modules/artistAlbums'
],

function (App, Backbone, Artistbio, ArtistRelated, ArtistAlbums) {

    var Artist = App.module();

    Artist.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'artist',
        beforeRender: function() {
            var artistbioCollection = new Artistbio.ArtistbioCollection();
            artistbioCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView(new Artistbio.View({collection: artistbioCollection}));
            artistbioCollection.fetch();

            var artistalbumsCollection = new ArtistAlbums.ArtistAlbumsCollection();
            artistalbumsCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView(new ArtistAlbums.View({collection: artistalbumsCollection}));
            artistalbumsCollection.fetch();             

            var artistrelatedCollection = new ArtistRelated.ArtistRelatedCollection();
            artistrelatedCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView(new ArtistRelated.View({collection: artistrelatedCollection}));
            artistrelatedCollection.fetch();
        },
    });

    return Artist;
});
```

could there be something wrong with my Codeigniter REST_Controller query??

Answer (score 0):

You must get the artistId somewhere and pass it to the collection url function :

```
url: function() {
    return '/projects/mdk/index.php/api/artistchannel/artist_bio/' +
    /* something like this.options.artistId */;
}
```

---

Change this `this.artistView.artist_id = id;` by this `this.artistView.collection.artist_id = id;`

Comment: yes, I got `return '/projects/mdk/index.php/api/artistchannel/artist_bio/' + this.artistId;` - but now, I get PHP error about `Undefined variable: artist_id` ??

Comment: Where did you pass the `artistId` parameter ?

Comment: that gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'artist_id' of undefined`

Comment: Where did you declare `this.artistView` ? can you create a jsfiddle ?